# Need TabBarController to be right to left RTL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

Am using TabBarController in my ios7 project 
and i need this TabBarController to be RTL so "More" 
Button will appear in the left side of the screen 
any idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can put you Tab Bar buttons in any order. However, I'd review what Apple's Human Interaction guide may have to say about that, as More buttons are generally found on the far right & you wouldn't want your app rejected for it.